# Java Json String extract number and replace specific text

Tags: java, json, regex

I have a text file in json, and I want to replace `NumberInt(x)` with the number `x`.

In the text file, there are records/data which is in json that has a field `workYear: NumberInt(2010)` as an example.

I want to replace this into `workYear: 2010` by removing `NumberInt(` and `)`.
This `NumberInt(x)` is located anywhere in text file and I want to replace all of it with its number.

I can search all the occurences of this, but I am not sure how to replace it with just the number value.

```
String json = <json-file-content>

String sPattern = "NumberInt\\([0-9]+\\)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sPattern);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json);

while (matcher.find()) {
    String s = matcher.group(0);
    int workYear = Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
    System.out.println(workYear);
}
```

I would like to replace all the `NumberInt(x)` with just the number value int `json` String... then I will update the text file (json file).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following should work. You need to capture the tokens.

```
    String json = "workYear:NumberInt(2010) workYear:NumberInt(2011)";
    String sPattern = "NumberInt\\(([0-9]+)\\)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json);

    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String s = matcher.group(1);
        numbers.add(s);
    }
    for (String number: numbers) {

        json = json.replaceAll(String.format("NumberInt\\(%s\\)", number), number);
    }
    System.out.println(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build the output using a `StringBuilder` like below,
Please refer to JavaDoc for [appendReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) for info on how this works.

```
    String s = "workYear: NumberInt(2010)\nworkYear: NumberInt(2012)";
    String sPattern = "NumberInt\\([0-9]+\\)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String s2 = matcher.group(0);
        int workYear = Integer.parseInt(s2.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf(workYear));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);

    String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it is not using StringBuilder... only StringBuffer. Also, It stopped on line 75439 still checking why it stopped there but it did not get any error.

Comment: is it the last line? i added `matcher.appendTail(sb);` to appen any remaining text to Builder/Buffer.. Also, if input is very large, you could split by lines and do this and merge lines.